# onclick returns function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've a Bootstrap modal for changing a user's password. The problem, however, is that no matter what I try I cannot get the event to fire, be it via `onclick` or by attaching the button to an event using `.on`. It simply will not recognise it.

I've tried putting the `<script>` tags above the modal, below the modal, and even inside the modal, only to always have `onclick` return `Uncaught ReferenceError: updatePassword is not defined`. I then removed the `onclick`, assigned an ID to the submit button, and tried `$('#update-password').on('click', function() { ... });` but this wasn't recognised at all.

The culprit in all of this is almost definitely the Bootstrap modal, and I'm guessing it's got something to do with how the browser handles it upon page load.

--

**Modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="changePasswordModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="changePassModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="changePassModalLabel">Change Password</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-password" style="display: none;">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form role="form" action="#" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password-current">Current Password<span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password-current" name="pass-curr" placeholder="Current password...">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password-new">New Password<span>*</span></label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password-new" name="pass-new" placeholder="New password...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password-new-conf">Confirm New Password<span>*</span></label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password-new-conf" name="pass-new-c" placeholder="Confirm new password...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updatePassword()">Update Password</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    function updatePassword(){
        console.log('foo');
        /*$.ajax({
            url: url+"ajax/update_password",
            data: {pass-curr : pass-curr, pass-new : pass-new, pass-new-c : pass-new-c},
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(data) {
                $('#alert-password').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger').html('<p><strong>Sorry, an error occurred!</strong></p><p>'+data.additional+'</p>').slideDown(200, function() {
                    $('#alert-password').delay(4000).slideUp(200);
                });
            }
        })*/
    };
</script>
```

*My apologies if this has been asked before. The only questions I could seem to find were those asking how to launch a modal through onclick.*

Comment: do u include JQuery Library ?

Comment: @user1428716 Yes it is included in the head of the document. I find it bizarre to say the least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your event is not getting binded with button

Please find the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w0c60uek/) here

In your HTML - do the following in the script tag

```
    <head> 
    <script> 

    function updatePassword(){

        console.log('updatePassword');

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){


       // $('.btn-primary').on('click',function(){ - This too works
         //   console.log('foo');     
        //});

         $('.btn-primary').on('click',updatePassword);


    });

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer as that solves the problem code provided. However, the actual reason the `.on` handler wasn't being recognised is because one of my variables within, `pass-cur`, is apparently illegal. It's interesting because despite `console.log('foo');` being the first line, `pass-cur = value;` breaks the entirety of the function making debugging it a nightmare, to the point where console outputs nothing...! Thank you for your time anyway.